# Properly dispose derived class

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable

I am trying to implement the **IDisposable** pattern on a derived class, and it's not working as expecting to work,

Suppose I have two classes and I want to call the **Dispose** method of the derived class:

Below is the code of my base class

```
public class BaseClass : IDisposable
{
    // To detect redundant calls
    private bool _disposedValue;

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
            // TODO: set large fields to null
            _disposedValue = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And I've something like this as a derived class

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // To detect redundant calls
    private bool _disposedValue;

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                
            }

            _disposedValue = true;
        }

        // Call base class implementation.
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And I've some wrapper class

```
public class WrapperClass : IDisposable
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<BaseClass> Items { get; set;}

    // To detect redundant calls
    private bool _disposedValue;

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                    foreach (var item in Items)
                    {
                        item.Dispose();
                    }
            }

            _disposedValue = true;
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is in the wrapper class, it doesn't call the **Dispose** method of the **DerivedClass**, and it calls the Dispose method of the **BaseClass** instead.

**Update**

It's my bad, I forget to say that the collections of items were created by **NSubstitute** like below:

```
// Having this will not call the Dispose method of the derived class
Items = new ReadOnlyCollection<BaseClass>(new List<BaseClass>
{
    Substitute.For<DerivedClass>()
})

// Having this will call the Dispose method of the derived class
Items = new ReadOnlyCollection<BaseClass>(new List<BaseClass>
{
    new DerivedClass>()
})
```

Comment: Your wrapper class disposes items which you dont show in your code.

Comment: Yes, i'll update my post :)

Comment: Please re-read [mre] and [edit] the code to show example that demonstrates the problem. The code posted in the question does not show what objects are added to the collection nor how you confirmed that for an instance of DerivedClass the `void Dispose(bool disposing)` is not called.

Comment: How would you use this to demonstrate that `DerivedClass.Dispose(bool)` isn't being called? `WrapperClass`'s constructor is private so how would you create it? If you make the constructor public, it [works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zGSX5J) as expected.

Comment: Sorry, all constructors all public, I have updated my post.

Comment: If you're disposing of the objects by way of `using`s (or calling `Dipose()` directly), what you have works. If you're letting the finalizer deal with it, keep in mind that .NET Core won't call the finalizer when the process is terminating. The finalizer is a last-ditch effort to free a resource when you didn't do it explicitly. If you don't have *unmanaged* resources, i.e. things you dispose regardless of the value of `disposing`, you don't need the finalizer.

Comment: this is the only way to implement it "properly" - read the doc from those who developed .net and knows better than SO layabouts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#implement-the-dispose-pattern-for-a-derived-class

Answer (score 1):

The public implementation of the `Dispose()` pattern in the documentation is there as an example to handle every case and contingency. It's always "safe" to do the whole thing, but it's also true that most of the time you can skip most of the pattern.

Especially regarding finalizers: you should only need a finalizer if you are creating an original wrapper implementation for a brand new kind of unmanaged resource. Each unmanaged resource type only needs **one** finalizer, at the root of the `IDisposable` inheritance tree. And if you don't add a finalizer, you don't need to worry about `GC.SuppressFinalize()`. Remove that, and some other balls drop as well.

In short, we can reduce the pattern for your `DerivedClass` all the way down to this:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{

}
```

This `DerivedClass` type still provides the `Dispose()` method and `IDisposable` implementation inherited from it's parent, and if it doesn't introduce any other unmanaged resources that's all it needs.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you about the usage of GC.SuppressFinalize(), where and when to use finalizers but, I think I should at least override the Dispose method in DirevedClass to dispose the managed referenced resources.

Comment: @MselmiAli Managed reference resources are _already handled by the garbage collector_. That's what "managed" means. Overriding `Dispose()` will do nothing to address them, because they are already handled. If that was a typo and you meant _unmanaged_ resources, then show them to me. What we see of `DerivedClass` introduces no new unmanaged resources that aren't already covered by the Dispose() method in `BaseClass`. Therefore no reason to do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is in the wrapper class, it doesn't call the Dispose method of the DerivedClass, and it calls the Dispose method of the BaseClass instead.

When the base.Dispose() calls Dispose(true) the method override in the derived class is executed, which in turn will call base. Dispose(true).

Answer (score -1):

`DerivedClass` doesn't appear to override `Dispose()`. Consequently, the base class version is invoked.

Add a `public void Dispose()` method that calls your `protected void Dispose(bool disposing)` implementation in `DerivedClass`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, but adding a finalizer that calls the Dispose like below fixed the issue.    ~DerivedClass() => this.Dispose(false);

Comment: The finalizer belongs on the base class. All control over the Disposable pattern (i.e. how `Dispose(bool)` is called) belongs there.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The Disposable pattern implements `IDisposable.Dispose` (by way of the public `Dispose` method, in this case) in the base class and calls the virtual `Dispose(bool)` method. Derived classes override that; that's all they need to do. The pattern is correctly implemented (or at least that aspect of it is). OP has claimed that `DerivedClass.Dispose(bool)` is not being called but this claim is unsubstantiated.

Comment: @madreflection Changes were made to the question after I posted my answer. At that time, I was solving for this statement from the post: "My issue is in the wrapper class, it doesn't call the Dispose method of the DerivedClass, and it calls the Dispose method of the BaseClass instead."

Comment: Yes, my comment was about the original post and your answer to that. And if you see the Fiddle I linked, I disproved OP's claim. What you suggested subverted the Disposable pattern, which OP correctly implemented, and didn't solve the problem at hand.

Comment: OP's comment about the finalizer shows that the quesiton left out that important detail. As I pointed out, though, in a comment on the question, finalizers are not called at the end of the program in .NET Core. .NET Framework would try to do it, but doesn't guarantee it. .NET Core doesn't even attempt it, by design. So OP shouldn't rely on the finalizer, but if it has to be there for *unmanaged* resources to be reclaimed while the program is running, it needs to be in the base class with `IDisposable.Dispose()`.